# jQuery unable to detect class changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment, I'm using the wonderful [roundabout(slider)](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/) plugin by Fred from FredHQ. The roundabout plugin adds the class '.roundabout-in-focus' to the currently focused slide, and removes it as soon as it progresses, and I wanted to add a click event to slides that weren't in focus, using this line of code:

`$(".roundabout-moveable-item:not(.roundabout-in-focus)").click"(function(){});`

This should work, but it refuses to acknowledge that the slide in focus has changed, and fails to match any click when used with .live() or .delegate(). What's going on?

[For context, see Line 111, on this page.](http://lightning.zsh.jp/testbed/redstonepowered)

Answer (score 6):

Your selector is not correct.  This part is not valid:

```
#.roundabout-moveable-item
```

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
.roundabout-moveable-item
```

---

When you do this:

```
$(".roundabout-moveable-item:not(.roundabout-in-focus)").click"(function(){});
```

It is evaluating your selector at the time the code runs.  It does not adapt to dynamic changes such as when `.roundabout-in-focus` is added or removed.  If you want it to adapt to dynamic changes, then you need to use one of the real-time event handlers such as `.live()` (pre-jquery-1.7) or `.on()` in jquery 1.7.

Comment: Whoops. I typo'd in the post, but on the page itself the syntax is just fine.

Comment: I added more to the end of my answer.

Comment: I mentioned this before, but using .live() doesn't register any clicks at all for me, my syntax is:  `$(".roundabout-moveable-item:not(.roundabout-in-focus)").live("click", function(){}`   
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's something wrong with your page/code because the general concept and the code you've included here works fine in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vjbr6/.

Comment: I wanted to be able to redirect the focused li on click. Using .live(), it helped. I used :
$('li.roundabout-in-focus').live("click", function(){
 window.location.href = "page.html";
});